# Command Key Doesn't Select Multiple Non-consecutive Sections of Text

Tags: microsoft-word, imac, magic-mouse

The normal behavior of using the Command key and the mouse to select multiple, non-consecutive sections of text has stopped working. I am working in a normal Word document, in the print view. Highlighting text, then moving to another section and holding down the Command key, when I click with the mouse the previously highlighted selection turns off. It does work as expected in other apps such as Excel or Notes.

I had this issue the other day working in Keynote, and I found a recommendation to switch from the Navigator to the Light Table view which worked, and then when I switched back to Navigator view it worked normally again.

Can someone advise on how to correct this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the temporary solution for the issue in Word for Mac 2016:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_mac-mso_mac2016/multiple-select-using-command-on-mac-is-gone/36450ab6-03f4-4724-9542-4cdfe9736209?auth=1

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. I see that the builders are working on it and hope it will be fixed soon. Any other suggestions welcome!